# Use register_post_type() to modify an existing post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

There are lots of situations where a theme or plugin registers a post type and you want to modify it. There is of course `add_post_type_support()` and `remove_post_type_support()`, but those don't give access to the full list of arguments that `register_post_type()` takes. In particular, maybe I want to disable a post type archive, hide the admin UI, hide from search, etc. while leaving the rest of the post type settings alone.

The [Codex page for `register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) dangles this in front of me:

> ### Description
>
> Create or modify a post type.

But in the past, when I've try to do this, it hasn't seemed to work. Is this function really for modifying post types, and if so, can you simply redeclare a couple arguments and leave the rest alone?

Seeing that there [isn't even a `deregister_post_type()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14761), I don't understand how it can be done.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is this function really for modifying post types

Yes.

> and if so, can you simply redeclare a couple arguments and leave the rest alone?

No. If you want to modify arguments to a post type, you need to use `get_post_type_object` to get the post type object, modify what you want in it, then re-register it using your modified type as the new $args parameter.

Comment: Would making two consecutive calls with modified arguments to the same `register_post_type` be correct? I assume so by your "Yes.", and it doesn't dumps any errors and has the desired effect. The real case is the second option I present in this answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74331/12615

Comment: Yes, that works, but it seems like if you're having to do that, then you need to add some filters or something else to prevent having to repeatedly register the same post type over and over again. Basically, get the arguments sorted out first, then register it.

Comment: I just thought about it because of the hook provided just before the plugin's `register_post_type`. In reality, there's no need. It was a "for the records" question, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 55):

After some research I found none of these answers are up to date.

As of December 8, 2015 WordPress includes a new filter, `register_post_type_args`, which lets you hook into the arguments of a registered post type.

```
function wp1482371_custom_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type == "animal-species" ) {
        $args['rewrite'] = array(
            'slug' => 'animal'
        );
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wp1482371_custom_post_type_args', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: This is the right way to do this now.

Comment: This should the the accepted answer

Comment: What if you need to update it after it has been registered in runtime? Eg: after `init`

Comment: @LucasBustamante It does not matter. Just call the 'add_filter' line during your plugin/theme, not in an action. The filter will be called during every `register_post_type` function. The only scenario where my code will not work is if the post type is not being registered correctly. All post types should be registered during the init hook. From the codex: "register_post_type will not work if called before 'init', and aspects of the newly created or modified post type will work incorrectly if called later." If you still need help I suggest posting more details in a new question.

Comment: so, this code will change the 'slug-of-post', as in 'sitename/projects/slug-of-post' ??

Comment: @Krys Not sure what you mean but to clarify: If you have "example.org/animal-species/slug-of-post", it lets you change "animal-species" to simply "animal" so the URL would become "example.org/animal/slug-of-post" and the archive page, if enabled, would be "example.org/animal/". Without needing to change the post type name.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example of how to use the `'registered_post_type'` filter to modify a post type in another plugin.

A plugin I was using didn't include a menu_icon in it's definition, so I wanted to add one of my own.

```
<?php
/**
 * Add a menu icon to the WP-VeriteCo Timeline CPT
 *
 * The timeline plugin doesn't have a menu icon, so we hook into 'registered_post_type'
 * and add our own.
 *
 * @param  string $post_type the name of the post type
 * @param  object $args the post type args
 */
function wpse_65075_modify_timeline_menu_icon( $post_type, $args ) {
    // Make sure we're only editing the post type we want
    if ( 'timeline' != $post_type )
        return;

    // Set menu icon
    $args->menu_icon = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/admin/menu-timeline.png';

    // Modify post type object
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types[$post_type] = $args;
}
add_action( 'registered_post_type', 'wpse_65075_modify_timeline_menu_icon', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner way to do it in most cases; however, it should be noted that this filter is too late to get picked up by rewrites so the accepted answer must be used instead in those situations.

Answer (score 4):

Hook into `'registered_post_type'` after the other code has registered it. It is called at the end of `register_post_type()`. You get two arguments: `$post_type` and `$args`.
Now you can change anything for this post type. Inspect `$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']` for some options.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me toward that hook. That answers the (more important) question about _how_ to modify a post type, but what about the description of `register_post_type()` that includes "modify?" Is that just wrong? Should I hop on my internet horse and vanquish it from the Codex this moment?

Comment: `$wp_post_types[$post_type] = $args;` … suggests that you should be able to change the properties. Add an example of the failing code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same thing with [The Events Calendar](https://theeventscalendar.com) plugin.

I added the below code to function.php to modify the **tribe_organizer** post type

```
function tribe_modify_organizer() {
 //New arguments
    $tribe_organizer_args = get_post_type_object('tribe_organizer'); // get the post type to modify
    $tribe_organizer_args-> taxonomies = array('post_tag' , 'tribe_events_cat'); // add taxonomies support
    $tribe_organizer_args-> exclude_from_search = false; // show in search result
 //re-register the same post type includeing the new args
    register_post_type( 'tribe_organizer', $tribe_organizer_args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tribe_modify_organizer', 100 );
```

Comment: Great sample, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is ugly, but you could alter the `GLOBAL` placeholder "on the fly" whenever you need to manipulate a single argument. This is how we use a non-public post type `contents` to be acceptable in admin menu. We hook close before and close after the menu renders:

```
function entex_theme_make_contents_public(){
    $GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['contents']->public = true;
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'entex_theme_make_contents_public', 10);

function entex_theme_make_contents_private_again(){
    $GLOBALS['wp_post_types']['contents']->public = '';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'entex_theme_make_contents_private_again', 12);
```

In our case, we want the Admin Menu Post List plugin to accept our post type, as they call `return get_post_types(array('public' => true));` inside their hook with priority 11 ...

Developers -Please make a comment if this could couse any issues.