# Download Free Trial After Email Entered

Tags: email

For my Wordpress site, it would be useful if I could allow people access to a resource if they entered an email address. Ideally the user would enter an email address and then be given a link to download the resource.

Note: I am not looking for support on third-party plugins. I am looking for useful suggestions on how this could be done with Wordpress. If there's a plugin that could do that, I would welcome the suggestion.

Comment: Can the people who marked this as off-topic please indicate why, please. Thanks.

Comment: Please read the flag message, your question is off topic due to the fact that woocommerce is a third party plugin for which we do not offer support for

Comment: I've also seen several questions being asked about Woocommerce. As an example : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74054/woocommerce-assign-an-author-to-a-product For more, check out this search : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=woocommerce

Comment: This was a highly debated topic, the fact that woocommerce dumped their support on sites like this. In the beginning, these type of questions was answered as you rightly pointed out. But it became to much. We can't take responsibilty for woocommerce's support. That is why it was desided to make questions relating woocommerce off topic. Check out [these questions](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=woocommerce) regarding woocommerce in the meta section

Comment: Ok, I have removed references to Woocommerce and made the question more generic.

Comment: What had you tried so far? Technically something as basic as having user simply register WordPress account fits this.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I was looking for something more automated that could use existing content. Ideally something where the user enters an email and is given a link to download. I have been experimenting with Forms plugins but nothing yet.