# How to enable parent-child relationships and post attribute admin widget for posts

Tags: custom-post-types, page-attributes

I want to be able to select a parent post when i create a new post. I assume it should be easy  just to make the 'page attributes' admin widget to work similarly for posts too. 
The use case is for this site: [thedevs.org](http://thedevs.org) where i want to enable people to post projects then later on make new posts that are children to a project post and would be listed under the parent post.
I am slightly new to wordpress but i play around with php quite easily. A working plugin or code snippet would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use register\_post\_type() to modify an existing post type](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65075/use-register-post-type-to-modify-an-existing-post-type)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that controls post-type hierarchy is called `'hierarchical'`, and is set when the post type is registered via [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). WordPress core registers the `'post'` post-type with `'hierarchical' => false`.

To override this setting, [refer to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65075/use-register-post-type-to-modify-an-existing-post-type).

Comment: Thank you, but sorry, i have no idea how post-type works or where i should plug in the functions to see the magic. Please help me like a 2 year old (in wordpress)...

Comment: NOW, I have been able to create a new custom post type but I still dont see the 'page attributes' admin widget in order to choose parent. How do i make this happen?

Comment: That's a separate question from your OP. Please start a new question, or else **edit** your question to change the scope, and paste in your `register_post_type()` code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code on my ..mytheme/functions.php file sort of worked for me:

```
            /* Register Custom Post Type for Projects*/
            add_action('init', 'project_post_type_init');
            function project_post_type_init() {
              $labels = array(
                'name' => _x('My Projects', 'post type general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Project', 'post type singular name'),
                'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Project'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Project'),
                'new_item' => __('New Project'),
                'view_item' => __('View Project'),
                'search_items' => __('Search Projects'),
                'not_found' =>  __('No Projects found'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Projects found in Trash'),
                'parent_item_colon' => __('Post'),
                'parent' => __('Post'),
              );
              $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui' => true, //false - to hide from the admin area menu
                'rewrite' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => true, //allow parent pages
                'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                'menu_position' => 1000,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'page-attributes')
              );
              register_post_type('project',$args);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through below Documentation and add the function in your functions.php
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support

Comment: Please improve your answer. While the link might answer the question, you should include the essential parts of the answer here and only provide the link for reference.