# How to modify a taxonomy that's already registered

Tags: custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy, wp-parse-args

Today I needed to change the arguments on a custom taxonomy that was already registered by a [third party plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/people-profile-cpt/). Specifically I wanted to set the `show_admin_column` argument to `true` and change the `rewrite` slug so that it wasn't just the taxonomy slug. In this case, it was a "People" post type with a "People Category" custom taxonomy.

I was surprised this wasn't asked before, so here's a question and answer.

Comment: Just a side note for anyone getting stuck, remember to flush the permalinks before checking the result.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) is the tool for the job. From the Codex:

> This function adds or overwrites a taxonomy.

One option would be to copy the `register_taxonomy()` `$args` and modify them. However, that would mean that any future changes to the original `register_taxonomy()` code would be overwritten.

Therefore, at least in this case, it's preferable to get the original arguments, modify the ones I want to change, and then re-register the taxonomy. Inspiration for this solution goes to @Otto in this [answer to a similar question about custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/65088/9844).

Using the `people` custom post type and `people_category` taxonomy from the example, this'll do it:

```
function wpse_modify_taxonomy() {
    // get the arguments of the already-registered taxonomy
    $people_category_args = get_taxonomy( 'people_category' ); // returns an object

    // make changes to the args
    // in this example there are three changes
    // again, note that it's an object
    $people_category_args->show_admin_column = true;
    $people_category_args->rewrite['slug'] = 'people';
    $people_category_args->rewrite['with_front'] = false;

    // re-register the taxonomy
    register_taxonomy( 'people_category', 'people', (array) $people_category_args );
}
// hook it up to 11 so that it overrides the original register_taxonomy function
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_modify_taxonomy', 11 );
```

Note above that I typecast the third `register_taxonomy()` argument to the expected array type. This isn't strictly necessary as `register_taxonomy()` uses [`wp_parse_args()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args) which can handle an `object` or `array`. That said, `register_taxonomy()`'s `$args` are supposed to be submitted as an `array` according to the Codex, so this feels right to me.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in order to change a flat taxonomy to a hierarchical taxonomy. I'm simply changing the hierarchical property to true. By doing this, it causes two meta boxes for the taxonomy on the right of the post edit screen, and I'm unable to actually add taxonomies...

Comment: Make sure you use the same slug (e.g. `'people_category'`) as the original taxonomy so that you overwrite it.

Comment: Genius! Pure genius! Worked perfectly!

Comment: I found an issue with this solution : the `capabilities` parameter is stored internally as `cap` so it won't be passed to the new registered taxonomy. [See my answer to a similar question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211672/how-to-overwrite-a-specific-parameter-in-a-core-taxonomy/211729#211729)

Comment: seems adding `flush_rewrite_rules();` after `register_taxonomy` is necessary for applying rewrite rules of new slug

Comment: @SajjadShirazy That's not recommended as that will flush the rewrite rules on every page load. You're better off to going to Settings > Permalinks to manually flush them once.

Comment: This is wonderful, I used it to add hierarchical urls to a custom taxonomy.

Comment: This is sweet like chocolate. Thank you, have a great day.

Comment: I used this to make the permalinks of my custom taxonomy hierarchical. But now these url's with an hierarchical taxonomy return a 404 Page not found. I also resaved the permalinks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', function( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type ) {
    if( $taxonomy !== 'people_category' || ! $object_type || $object_type[0] !== 'people' ) return $args;
    $args['show_admin_column'] = true;
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'people';
    return $args;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: This is the proper way of doing it nowadays. Don't forget to resave the Permalinks in Settings.