# Change existing taxonomy settings when using custom taxonomy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

For a plugin I have created a new custom taxonomy for attachments using the function register_taxonomy() and parameters like "show_admin_column". When this parameter is set to true, it shows the category column as expected.
I also used register_taxonomy_for_object_type() to register the existing 'category' taxonomy to the same attachment post_type. As the "show_admin_column" for 'category' is also set to true, it shows the category column as expected.

Depending on the setting of an option in my plugin, I would like to show only one of the taxonomies. Not displaying the custom taxonomy is no problem, just define the value of "show_admin_column" to false when using register_taxonomy().

However, my question now is how do I switch the value to false for the 'category' taxonomy as the function register_taxonomy_for_object_type() doesn't seem to have any arguments.

I would like to have a function like set_taxonomy_args($taxonomy, args).

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a taxonomy that's already registered](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161788/how-to-modify-a-taxonomy-thats-already-registered)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I think I have searched for the wrong question.
It seems like the answer to my question can be found in [How to modify a taxonomy that's already registered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161788/how-to-modify-a-taxonomy-thats-already-registered?rq=1).

Thanks to @helgatheviking !