# How to overwrite a specific parameter in a core taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy

[The Codex page for `register_taxonomy` says that](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

> This function adds or overwrites a taxonomy.

How can I use it to overwrite a core taxonomy without redefining all the parameters ?

For example, let's imagine that I want to make the core posts categories read-only for everybody. I can achieve that by setting the `edit_terms` capability for this taxonomy to `do_not_allow`.

My first guest was to call the `register_taxonomy` with only the parameter I want to change :

```
add_action( 'init', 'u16975_disable_category_creation' );
function u16975_disable_category_creation(){
    register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', array(
        'capabilities' => array(
            'edit_terms' => 'do_not_allow',
        ),
    ) );
}
```

But this does not work as it also overwrites all other parameters and set them to the default value (ex: `hierarchical` is set back to `false`).

The only way I found to achieve this is to use the global variable that stores all registered taxonomies.

```
add_action( 'init', 'u16975_use_global_var' );
function u16975_use_global_var(){
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $wp_taxonomies['category']->cap->edit_terms = 'do_not_allow';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another reliable way to overwrite a taxonomy : I can just get the registered one before and change only the parameter I want. Registered taxonomies can be retrieved by `get_taxonomy`. But there are two catches :

1. `get_taxonomy` returns an object, whereas `register_taxonomy` ask for an associative array, so we need a type cast.
2. the `capabilities` parameter is stored as `cap` internally, so we need to change its name.

Here is the code :

```
add_action( 'init', 'u16975_disable_category_creation' );
function u16975_disable_category_creation(){
    $tax = get_taxonomy( 'category' );
    $tax->capabilities = (array)$tax->cap;
    $tax->capabilities['edit_terms'] = 'do_not_allow';
    register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', (array)$tax );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Version 4.4 saw the introduction of the `register_taxonomy_args` filter in [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) which you can use to filter the arguments used to register a taxonomy

```
/**
 * Filter the arguments for registering a taxonomy.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param array  $args        Array of arguments for registering a taxonomy.
 * @param array  $object_type Array of names of object types for the taxonomy.
 * @param string $taxonomy    Taxonomy key.
 */
$args = apply_filters( 'register_taxonomy_args', $args, $taxonomy, (array) $object_type );
```

So you can do the following:

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', function ( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type )
{
    // Only target the built-in taxonomy 'category'
    if ( 'category' !== $taxonomy )
        return $args;

    // Set our capability 'edit_terms' to our value
    $args["capabilities"]["edit_terms"] = 'do_not_allow';

    return $args;
}, 10, 3);
```

On all older versions, you would either need to re-register the complete 'category' taxonomy or use the way you have done it in your question

### EDIT

> The Codex page for `register_taxonomy` says that
>
> - This function adds or overwrites a taxonomy.

That is exactly what it does, it either creates a custom taxonomy or completely overrides and register a core taxonomy, it does not add any extra arguments to the existing taxonomy

Comment: Thanks for you answer Pieter. The filter you mentioned sounds interesting, but I'm still using 4.3 for a few days. Also the issue with this filter is that you have to register on it before the `init` hook, and in my case I want to execute this code only on a particular admin page, so I use the `admin_head-$page_hook` action.

Comment: No problem. You shouldn't wait to long to upgrade as Version 4.4 offers quite a lot of new interesting features which you are missing out on :-)