# Change permalinks for post type 'post' only

Tags: posts, permalinks

Like many other, I would like to have:
*domain.com/post-title*
changed into
*domain.com/blog/post-title*
but only for the post type 'post', not for 'page' and especially not for the custom post types (of which my theme seems to have many).

I have done my research on this forum and other sources and I know the general answer seems to be:

> When you register your post type, the with_front argument of rewrite should be false.

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),
); 
register_post_type( 'your-post-type', $args );
```

Unfortunately, this does not help the beginners. We don't know what is meant by the instructions above. Apparently we should somehow re-register the default post type "post" (although the post type "post" already exists and is in use), but we don't know how and where to do that. If anyone can shed some light on the necessary procedure for changing the blog posts URLs, I would be most grateful.

Comment: `post` post type settings are controlled on the Settings > Permalinks admin screen.

Comment: @Milo Thank you. Indeed, there are some URL settings that can be controlled that way. However, in my particular case though, I only want to change URL setting for posts that have the type 'post'. 
More precisely, if I go to permalink settings -> Common settings and instead of the current: "Post name" checked option I select 'Custom structure'  and write '/blog/%postname%', not only all my blog posts will have the 'blog' word prepended to the URL, but also all my custom post types. This is not the desired outcome.

Comment: You’ve already got the answer to that problem, custom types should of be registered with `with_front` set to `false` as you’ve described in your question above.

Comment: @Milo Since these custom types are created by the theme developers, we, the beginer wordpress users, do not know what is meant by registering a custom type. Therefore our question refers precisely to what it is that we need to do to register and where. Should we include the mentioned coded in a functions.php file in a child theme that inherits the main theme we use ? In that case, wouldn't this mean we are re-registering a custom type, since it is already registered in the parent theme ?
Full disclosure: I have already tried doing the above and it has no effect, their link still changes.

Comment: If you don't control the code that registers the post type, then there is a filter that lets you alter the arguments without having to re-register the post type. See [this question and answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305391/prepend-regular-posts-with-custom-slug-without-affecting-custom-post-types) for an example.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/230313/128304). Remember to pop in there and give it a like.

I'll post it here, for people in a rush.

---

Put this into the `functions.php`-file:

```
function wp1482371_custom_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
  if ( $post_type == "post" ) {
    $args['rewrite'] = array(
      'slug' => 'blog'
    );
  }

  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wp1482371_custom_post_type_args', 20, 2 );
```

(Tested and works).

*Remember!!*

**Remember A)** Remember to update your permalinks afterwards (by going into **Settings** >> **Permalinks** >> **Click 'Save Changes'** ).

**Remember B)** If you get wierd results, then try opening an incognito-window and see if it words there. WordPress has a feature that redirects to '[Nearest Matching URL](http://biostall.com/prevent-wordpress-redirecting-to-nearest-matching-url/)', that can seem confusing, when playing around with permalinks.

---

You could also try to find a Plugin that does it. I wouldn't do that, since it's quite extensive to add a plugin for that sole purpose. But hey, - sometimes it can be satisfying to shoot birds with canons (no bird was harmed making this joke).

Comment: A short and beautiful solution with a reasonable explanation. Sadly, it's not what I'm looking for. Currently, it uses the "rewrite" definition to redirect to the old permalink ("/blog/post' -> "/post"). However, I want it to keep the URL "/blog/post". How would you achieve that?

Comment: To extend this: One can fix it by adding the following: ```add_filter('pre_post_link', 'my_change_post_link', 10, 3);
function my_change_post_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  if (get_post_type($post) == 'post') {
    return "/blog" . $permalink;
  }
  return $permalink;
}```

Comment: @Chaoste OMG what are the chances I needed this the very next day.  Looked everywhere - TYTY

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in 2023, I can see the $args being updated, but they take no effect after updating permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
function generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
      $new_rules = array(
        '(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',     
        'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
        'blog/[^/]+/embed/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
        'blog/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&embed=true',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
        'blog/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&paged=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
      );
      $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    }
    add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'generate_rewrite_rules' );

    function update_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
      $post = get_post( $id );
      if( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        return home_url( '/blog/' . $post->post_name );
      }
      return $post_link;
    }
    add_filter( 'post_link', 'update_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
//Place code in function.php 
add_action('init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1); 
function my_new_default_post_type() 
{ 
    register_post_type('post', array(
        // 'labels' => $labels, 
        'public' => true, 
        //'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, 
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
        'capability_type' => 'post', 
        'map_meta_cap' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false, 
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/blog'), // Add your slug here 
        'query_var' => false, 
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats'),
    )); 
    /* If you add above code in function.php, Your blog pagination is stopped to working, You need to add rewrite rule using "Debug This" Plugin under Query >> Rewrite Section & modify your rewrite_rule. */ 
    add_rewrite_rule('(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=resources/blog&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I wouldn't do this, since it 're-registers' the `post`-post type.

Comment: You have need to change your permalink structure.