# Prepend regular Posts with custom slug, without affecting Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, blog

My company policy is to prepend "/blog/" to our Post slugs. Normally our SEO team will do this via the Custom Permalinks setting (/blog/%postname%), but this has the side effect of pre-pending /blog/ to other Custom Post Types as well.

I know I can set the `with_front` attribute to `false` when registering Custom Post Types to avoid this issue, but it's quite a pain when Themes add their own Custom Post Types, or if we inherit sites from other developers.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so, how do you get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `register_post_type_args` filter to alter post types registered by code you don't control.

You can set it for a specific type:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpd_change_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function wpd_change_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ){
    if( 'turnips' == $post_type ){
        $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Or remove that `$post_type` check to change it for all custom types.

Comment: This looks like it will work, the problem is I don't want to be risky and ever accidentally remove 'with_front' from custom post types in the future that DO need the Custom Permalink structure. Ideally there would be an option in WP's dashboard UI or a plugin that only affects default Posts permalinks. But oh well, your answer is super helpful and does answer my question