# understand what code is doing when prepending /blog

Tags: php, posts, permalinks

I am new to Wordpress and php coding.

We are moving from a different container system to wordpress and to keep the links intact I need to prepend /blog to all post articles.

I tried it through the individual permalink using https://www.example.com/blog/%postname%/

It works nicely for the post articles, but I realized that it seems to also impact i.e. custom layouts from Astra, making the following url: https://www.example.com/blog/astra-advanced-hook/12345

Although I am not sure this is an issue, but being an orderly person I really don't like such a strange URL convention.

So I searched the net and found the following reply from Zeth and Chaoste
[Change permalinks for post type 'post' only](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305372/change-permalinks-for-post-type-post-only)

```
function wp1482371_custom_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type == "post" ) {
        $args['rewrite'] = array(
            'slug' => 'blog'
        );
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wp1482371_custom_post_type_args', 20, 2 );

function my_change_post_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {   
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'post') {     
        return "/blog" . $permalink;   }   
    return $permalink; 
}

add_filter('pre_post_link', 'my_change_post_link', 10, 3);
```

I went on and created a child theme, posted the above to function php and it is working (when I posted just the first function and add_filter, there didn't seem to be any change). But being an inquisitive person, I would really like to know what exactly this is doing?

I guess add_filter is what triggers the function when some action happens. The if checks if it is the post type.

1. But what does the first function do and what does the second one do?
2. Why do I need both functions?

Thank you for helping me learn!

Comment: you would need to contact Pods support to get the answer to your 3rd question, 3rd party plugin support questions are offtopic here. I've edited it out so that your question doesn't get close votes as a 3rd party support question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wp1482371_custom_post_type_args', 20, 2 );
```

When you register a post type, this filter is called, and `wp1482371_custom_post_type_args` is using this opportunity to modify the parameters for the `post` post type to change the `slug`

```php
add_filter('pre_post_link', 'my_change_post_link', 10, 3);
```

Just because your posts are now available at a new URL, doesn't mean WordPress knows this and will change the permalinks! It's not psychic, it has to be told explicitly or the URLs shown in the user interface won't match and will still be missing the `/blog` part. `pre_post_link` gives you an opportunity to filter them, and if it's a post it add `/blog` to the beginning.

> 2.) Why do I need both functions?

Because if you just change the posts URL that doesn't mean WP knows what to do with /blog URLs.

And if you only add /blog URLs that doesn't mean WP knows to put /blog in front of every posts URL.

---

As an aside, just because you found this particular solution, does not mean it is the best solution. There are solutions that don't involve WordPress at all and sit deeper down at the Apache/Nginx level, you can also 301 redirect to versions that don't have `/blog`, as well as many other options.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I am probably still missing part of the understanding. How come WP does not know where the post is with the first function? It is telling it, to add the slug "blog". Is it not stating: hey WP, you post is now under blog/somepostname? WP just needs to check, if the slug is empty or not, no?

Comment: And what if I wrote in the first function slug=blog and in the second prepended "/somethingelsethanblog"? What would the result be? Telling the system twice about the "same" just seems like a potential place for typos and errors. (I do not know the system, I am just trying to learn. Thank you for supporting me.)

Comment: where can I read about the other options please? Is there some kind of a comparison of the different possibilities (pro/con) and how to execute them?

Comment: There is no comprehensive list of other options, and it's highly unlikely you will see a full list with comparisons and a pros/cons list. I think you're assuming that there is an interconnected system that tells WP when this changes, that too changes, and that's not the case. Remember WP is not a sentient AI, you're asking why it doesn't do X Y Z, and the answer is because it does not do X Y Z, somebody has to build that and nobody has built that.

Comment: URL becomes query vars, query vars go into `WP_Query`, `WP_Query` fetches posts, WP takes posts and query vars and picks a template, template loads and displays the posts. That's how you get from a URL to a page in the browser. Notice how deciding what the URL of a post is does not feature in that list, they are separate systems. Just because you've enabled a post to be visited at the URL `/bananas` does not mean the canonical URL of that post is now `/bananas`, that's a leap of logic, an expectation, these things need to be implemented, and it has not been implemented

Comment: Also notice some of the other options I suggested are not solutions to your questions, or even options for your problem, but rather they reframe the problem and change the requirements. E.g. redirects might redirect users from `/blog/xyz` to `/xyz` which is not what you asked for

Comment: It may help to know that WP does not know where any post is with the first function, it has no idea which post that URL is for, and many URLs can lead to the same post, either via indirection, redirects, code you added, etc, so the question "How come WP does not know where the post is with the first function?" does not make sense. Sure if you visit that URL with the first function you will arrive in the place you expected, but that doesn't mean WP knows in advance that's the canonical location of that post. Adding a new road to your house does not change every persons route automatically

Comment: Thank you for your patience Tom. As I understand, WP does not work with "physical" .html pages (posts) in folders, but all comes out of the database. So could I not just use function 2 alone? I guess I still don't understand what the functions do. The second one says "use /blog/something" as the actual URL, correct? But why then do I have the first function? What happens, if function 1 and two have different string inputs / typos and what if I did not "modify the parameters for the post post type to change the slug"? I filter on post and not the slug, so would 2 not be sufficient?

Comment: because if you only have the second function WP will display the new URL, but when the user clicks and follows it in their browser it will not map to anything and they will see a 404.. I suspect the confusion is because you've bundled multiple concepts up as a single thing when it is not. The `html` file mental model is not accurate here, and you can't replace HTML file with database row and expect it to work. _There is no filesystem equivalent of where the post lives that provides absolute certainty._ Many URLs can lead to a post, and there is no register of absolute URLs in the database

Comment: ok, so 2 sets the user link and then that is decoded based on the slug of 1? And if I have the URL /blog, but the slug does not say blog, I get a 404? Out of curiosity, how would I set a post to display under /blog/x and also under /golb/x? Then these functions would not work, because there is only 1 slug and 1 URL?

Comment: 2 and 1 do different things, stop trying to draw a connection as if one influences the other, they do not. You could make function 2 print out war and peace. You're muddling up 2 separate unconnected systems and trying to understand how they are connected when they are not. 1 function makes it so that the URL finds the post. The other function changes what the post reports as its URL. Function 2 could easily be modified to show a completely unrelated URL that isn't even on your site

Comment: One function changes where WordPress thinks the post lives. The other function allows that place to lead to the post. Just like moving house does not automatically send all your mail to the new house, you have to tell the postoffice, they are separate actions. Buying a house and hiring a removal truck doesn't redirect all your mail to the new location, and redirecting your mail doesn't mean you wake up in a new house.

Comment: Thank you Tom and understood. So is there a better way you know of, I should explore doing this (and have a ton of other questions :D )?