# Custom rewrite causes 404 on pagination

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination

I have custom rewrite rules in place so that the posts page URL can be `/blog/` and all posts have the URL structure `/blog/post-title-here/`, this works great, however I am getting a 404 error on the `/blog/` page pagination when it is structured like `/blog/page/2/` -- I've seen **many** topics and questions on this around StackOverflow, however it appears everything answered is for categories to be structured like `/blog/cat-name/page/2/` where I just need it `/blog/page/2/`

Here is my rewrite function in place to append `/blog/` to post URLs:

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'site_add_blog_rewrites' );
function site_add_blog_rewrites( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
    'blog/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' =>     'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' =>     'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
  ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

And then I am converting the post permalinks using:

```
function site_filter_post_link($permalink, $post) {
  if ($post->post_type != 'post') {
    return $permalink;
  }
  return 'blog'.$permalink;
}
add_filter('pre_post_link', 'site_filter_post_link', 10, 2);
```

Am I missing the proper rewrite to allow the URL structure `/blog/page/2/` or is this not possible because WP is thinking `/page/` should be a post when it is in this structure? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**NOTE:** I **cannot** have my permalinks structure `/%category%/%postname%/`. The permalinks must stay at `/%postname%/`

Comment: Why not just set permalink structure to `/blog/%postname%/`?

Comment: Well, there are 11 other custom post types that can't have `/blog/` in the URL. That structure is only needed for the 'post' post type, nothing else. Do you know of an easy route to remove that from all post types except `post`? Or is it possible to add `/blog/` as the slug to the `post` post type registration through a hook or action?

Comment: Custom post types should be registered with `with_front` set to `false` so they don't append the `post` front value. If you don't register those post types with your own code, then use [the `register_post_type_args` filter like in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/230313/4771).

Comment: That removes the post type slug from the URL too though? For example, if a post type is `food` I would need that post URL to be `/food/food-post-name`. I should also note I have a rewrite in place to remove a custom taxonomy base slug from the URL too.

Comment: No, with_front and slug are different things.

Comment: Well, even when changing `with_front` to false, the `/blog/` part of the URL is still included from the permalink structure... so that's not working.

Comment: Did you flush rules after?

Comment: Yep. Several times. I'm accepting defeat on this and going a different route. Will have to set a ton of 301 redirects for it, but I'm out of time unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this issue (this post is quite old), I found a very helpful snippet in this blog post: https://www.grzegorowski.com/wordpress-rewrite-rules

```
/**
 * Reprioritise pagination over displaying custom post type content
 */
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule('(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
});
```

This will ensure WP uses the pagination rule prior to the post type query rules