# How can I change the title of an Add New page in Admin for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, html

I have a custom post type called 'Bookmark'.

When users add a new Bookmark in the Admin, the title of the page is

## Add a new Page

Is there a hook (filter) to change this title to

## Add a new Bookmark

Comment: here you'll get your answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65075/use-register-post-type-to-modify-an-existing-post-type/65088

Comment: I have modified the existing custom post type with the help of the above link.
If you want it, let me know I can post this as an answer. Currently I don't see that's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're registering new post type with [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters), you can pass `labels` parameter (which is an array of labels used for that CPT).

You can customize these labels:

- 'name' - general name for the post type, usually plural. The same and overridden by $post_type_object->label. Default is Posts/Pages
- 'singular_name' - name for one object of this post type. Default is Post/Page
- 'add_new' - the add new text. The default is "Add New" for both hierarchical and non-hierarchical post types. When internationalizing this string, please use a gettext context matching your post type. Example: _x('Add New', 'product');
- 'add_new_item' - Default is Add New Post/Add New Page.
- 'edit_item' - Default is Edit Post/Edit Page.
- 'new_item' - Default is New Post/New Page.
- 'view_item' - Default is View Post/View Page.
- 'view_items' - Label for viewing post type archives. Default is 'View Posts' / 'View Pages'.
- 'search_items' - Default is Search Posts/Search Pages.
- 'not_found' - Default is No posts found/No pages found.
- 'not_found_in_trash' - Default is No posts found in Trash/No pages found in Trash.
- 'parent_item_colon' - This string isn't used on non-hierarchical types. In hierarchical ones the default is 'Parent Page:'.
- 'all_items' - String for the submenu. Default is All Posts/All Pages.
- 'archives' - String for use with archives in nav menus. Default is Post Archives/Page Archives.
- 'attributes' - Label for the attributes meta box. Default is 'Post Attributes' / 'Page Attributes'.
- 'insert_into_item' - String for the media frame button. Default is Insert into post/Insert into page.
- 'uploaded_to_this_item' - String for the media frame filter. Default is Uploaded to this post/Uploaded to this page.
- 'featured_image' - Default is Featured Image.
- 'set_featured_image' - Default is Set featured image.
- 'remove_featured_image' - Default is Remove featured image.
- 'use_featured_image' - Default is Use as featured image.
- 'menu_name' - Default is the same as `name`.
- 'filter_items_list' - String for the table views hidden heading.
- 'items_list_navigation' - String for the table pagination hidden heading.
- 'items_list' - String for the table hidden heading.
- 'name_admin_bar' - String for use in New in Admin menu bar. Default is the same as `singular_name`.

As you can see, `add_new_item` is the label that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

To change the label, add **add_new_item** in **labels array** passed when creating your custom post type. Below is an example of custom post type 'Events'.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {

  register_post_type( 'events',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Events' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Events' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Event' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add Event' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event' ),
            'featured_image' => __( 'Event Image' ),
            'set_featured_image' => __( 'Upload Event Image' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove Event Images' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Manage Events' ),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar',            
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
    )
  );
}
```

For more information about the changing labels in custom post type [refer this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Hope this helps.